# php application raises ORA-00903 although the table is present

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oci8

I am trying to program a PHP Web Application, for this application I do need a funtction to get the ID of a table and since I didnt want to work with an endlessly long `switch` i thought I would make the following function:

```
function getId($conn, string $col, string $tbl, string $val): int{
  $qry = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT :col FROM :tbl WHERE :col = :val");
  oci_bind_by_name($qry, ':tbl', $tbl);
  oci_bind_by_name($qry, ':col', $col);
  oci_bind_by_name($qry, ':val', $val);
  @$success = oci_execute($qry);

  if($success){
    //fetch data
  }else {
    $err = oci_error($qry);
    print_r($err);
    }
  }
}
```

I first thought it was because it wouldnt bind my variables, but I tested it and it returns `true` so binding seems to work. If I try to use the function i get the following error message:

```
Array
(
    [code] => 903
    [message] => ORA-00903: Invalid table name
    [offset] => 20
    [sqltext] => SELECT :col FROM HR.:tbl WHERE :col = :val;
)
```

I already read through some posts and I still cant find my error. I hope you can help me.

Comment: This won't work as noted in the other answer: bind variables are for data, not SQL text.  If you dynamically construct the SQL text inside PHP with string concatenation, make sure you DO NOT concatenate values passed in from the user since this will open you to SQL injection attacks. Make sure any such text is hardcoded in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to bind the table and column names in a prepared statement.  This isn't really a limitation on prepared statements, since in general the column and table structure would be different across different tables, and hence the same statements could not be reused anyway.

So I expect the following will work:

```
$qry = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT some_col FROM your_table WHERE some_col = :val");
oci_bind_by_name($qry, ':val', $val);
@$success = oci_execute($qry);
```

Internally I am also not sure what actually is happening here, but one possibility is that PHP is escaping your table name as a parameter.  In any case, it is not leading to a query which will run.

If you need to change the columns or table in a prepared statement, just go ahead and create another statement.

Comment: Let's keep comments for clarifying the question/answer and not about voting.